# cPanel Forwarders - Piping Emails to a Laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel, email, cpanel, email-forwarding

I'm trying to forward an email to my Laravel Application siting on a subdomain in cPanel.

That's why I've created an artisan command which is, for now, having just an info log: `\Log::info("Email sent!")`, that is writing this message whenever that command is executed.

In cPanels Forwarders I've added a new forwarder with a **Pipe to a Program** option, and the code included in that input field is: `/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/subdomain_folder/artisan mail-parse`.

This doesn't do anything when email is recieved, nothing is written in **storage/logs/laravel.log** file.

But, if I paste this same command `/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/subdomain_folder/artisan mail-parse` in a Terminal with SSH, laravel.log updates as expected.